# How to permit HTML to break at specified points?

Tags: html, text-formatting

I know about non-breaking spaces but I've got the opposite problem and Google doesn't even find anyone else asking the question.

I have a piece of text:  `<option A>/<option B>/<option C>` (the number of options is variable) that I want to break only at the slashes.  Keeping it from breaking elsewhere is trivial--replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces.  What I'm stumped on is permitting it to break after the slashes.  Do I just have to insert an extra space after the slashes even though that won't look as good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [<wbr>](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) tag to allow the browser to break at the slashes:

```
<option A><wbr>/<wbr><option B><wbr>/<wbr><option C>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I was after.  I figured there should be something like this but I was coming up dry on Google.

Comment: Too bad it's not standard.  +1 anyway; it *should* be standard.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Unicode Zero Width Space (U+200B). You can enter them directly as characters — `optionA​/​optionB​/​optionC` — or alternatively, since you can't really see the zero-width-spaces there, as character references: `optionA&#x200B;/&#x200B;optionB&#x200B;/&#x200B;optionC`.

Comment: Note that if you use this approach, the zero-width characters get copied when users copy and paste the text.